# Bootstrap 4: how to use NavBars without jQuery / minimal bootstrap.js?

Tags: bootstrap-4

The vast majority of pages on our site will only use GRID and NAVBAR.  It makes no sense for us to be loading all of jQuery and bootstrap.min.js on each page.

In fact, the only JS needed at all is the js to handle the opening/closing of NAVBAR on mobile requests.

Has anyone created a minimal, small .js that handles this?

I found a bunch for Bootstrap 3, but nothing that I can see for Bootstrap 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can use this:

https://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/v4.html

#### With cdn

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap.native@2.0.15/dist/bootstrap-native-v4.min.js"></script>
```

#### With npm

Run command:

```
npm install https://github.com/thednp/bootstrap.native
```

And import:

```
var bsn = require('bootstrap.native/dist/bootstrap-native-v4');
```

Answer (score -2):

jQuery is required for Bootstrap, and there is no avoiding that.

As [shown in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/#individual-or-compiled), you can use just the Navbar components you need (collapse.js and utils.js).